# vmdk file is required to power on the virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware

Can I recover the Guest machine as I have deleted the vmdk file from which I have installed the macOS? I have a separate folder for VM containing many vmdk files (partitions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially, yes.

In the VMs' settings, click the "Add Device" button in the top right hand corner, select "Existing Hard Disk", select the desired VMDK, and click the "Open" button.

After that, you should be set to power on the VM and hopefully it boots up.

Another alternative, create a new VM and point the configuration to one of the existing VMDKs.